# Error al pasar datos al metodo Mail::send laravel

Tags: laravel

Quiero enviar un correo de confirmación al usuario que ha solicitado el servicio, pero cuando intento pasarle el email y nombre a la clase de enviar correo, me da el siguiente error:

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send() must be of the type array, object given
```

El método que estoy utilizando para enviar el correo al usuario es el siguiente:

```
$dat =  \DB::table('vacations')->select('users.email', 'users.name')->join('users','users.id','=','vacations.user_id')
                ->where(['vacations.id' => $request->vacation_id])
                ->get();
    $name[]=$dat[0]->name;
    //dd($dat[0]->email,$name);
    Mail::send("correo.aprobado", $dat, function($message) use ($dat,$name){
       $message->to(['email'=>$dat[0]],['name'=>$dat[0]])
               ->subject("enhorabuena");
    });
```

el output de la variable $dat es este:

```
Collection {#265 ▼
#items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#256 ▼
      +"email": "user@example.es"
      +"name": "user"
    }
  ]
}
```

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error dice que le estás enviando un objeto, y si te das cuenta, tu variable `$dat` es un objeto de la clase `Collection`, para convertir tu colección a array solo mándalo como `$dat->toArray()`, quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Mail::send("correo.aprobado", $dat->toArray(), function($message) use ($dat,$name){
       dd($dat[0]->email);
       $message->to($dat[0]->email, $dat[0]->name)
               ->subject("enhorabuena");
    });
```

Es importante conocer las diferencias entre un array y una colección de Laravel, tal vez cuando hiciste esto: `$dat[0]->name` te dio la alusión a que es un array pero el operador `->` es para acceder a propiedades de un objeto, para cuando lo conviertas a array, para acceder a la propiedad `name` quedaría así `$dat[0]['name']`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si cambio eso, me da error, en el email ahora """ Address in mailbox given [email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2."""

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez Si, tenías que cambiar la parte del `$message->to...`, ya actualicé mi respuesta, ¿podrías checarla nuevamente?.

Comment: Bueno, va cambiando el error jeje. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. Parece que coje como array el email entonces no sirve, he probado a sacarlo de mi objeto tambien y meterlo en otra variable pero me dice lo mismo.

Comment: Copia exactamente como lo puse, en la parte de `use()`, mandé la variable como array. Adentro de la función callback, en donde está la parte de `$message->to...`, antes de eso usa un `dd($dat[0]['email'])` y checa que imprima una dirección de correo válida.

Comment: Esto no va ni para atras, creo que he probado todas las combinaciones posibles x( ya no se que mas hacerle, si quieres te pego los codigos que he ido probando, pero vamos, que siempre me sale el error de cannot use object, incluso poniendolo como me dices, por cierto, si pongo el use($dat-> me dice que tiene un operador no esperado) Gracias por tantas molestias

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez Lo he actualizado de nuevo, ¿podrías decirme que te imprime el `dd()`?

Comment: el e-mail sale correcto[[  "user@user.es"  ]] (sin los corchetes) pero si quito el dd devuelve este error: Address in mailbox given [email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82077/discussion-between-aaron-gutierrez-and-david-pazo-lopez).

Answer (score 0):

Publico respuesta ya que con tanto comentario y asi, queda un poco lioso:

Al final la solución viene por lo que dijo Aaron, de pasar el objeto a un array, el problema que tenia era que el metodo de Mail no lo interpretaba correctamente.

Quedando así el código:

```
$dat =  \DB::table('vacations')->select('users.email', 'users.name')->join('users','users.id','=','vacations.user_id')
                ->where(['vacations.id' => $request->vacation_id])
                ->get();
    Mail::send("correo.aprobado", $dat->toArray(), function($message) use ($dat){
        $message->to($dat[0]->email , $dat[0]->name)
                ->subject("Respuesta a su solicitud");
    });
```

Muchas gracias Aaron por tus aportaciones.